# NDK: How to include "RefBase.h" by ndkr15c?

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I have successfully include "rs/cpp/util/RefBase.h" by NDK r10, But after changed to NDK 15 and cmake, it compiles error: fatal error: 'rs/cpp/util/RefBase.h' file not found. My build parameters has not changed:

```
cmake {
    arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21',
              '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=stlport_static'
}
```

I have struggled by this for a long time, Thanks if anyone could help.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Like, what does your `CMakeLists.txt`look like; where in the filesystem does this `RefBase.h` file exist, etc. Also note that `stlport` was deprecated in NDK r17, and removed altogether in NDK r18.

Comment: Here is my cmake file:
    "cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")
    add_library(gl2jni SHARED
                gl_code.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(gl2jni
                          android
                          log 
                          EGL
                          GLESv2)"
My include 'rs/cpp/util/RefBase.h' is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like RenderScript support was ever added to CMake. You can use ndk-build and look at our tests to see how it's used: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/tests/device/rs-cpp-basic/jni/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := app
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= foo.rs app.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := RScpp_static
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/renderscript)
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed back to ndk-build command (r15c)，it build successfully. I figured why NDK didn't support public use of BaseRef/sp/wp and why are these classes under RenderScript directory.

Comment: They are not Android APIs, but rather an implementation detail of RenderScript. You should not use these directly. They may disappear at any time. If you need an implementation of a class like this you should create one in your code rather than importing an implementation detail.